# Vegetation coverage using NDVI

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, ndvi

I met a problem when I was using this equation f=(NDVI-NDVI MIN)/(NDVI MAX-NDVI MIN) to get vegetation cover.
The problem is “NDVI-NDVI MIN” part. NDVI value range is (-0.05115,0.605945)When I used Raster Calculate to run it, the result should be (0,0.657098), but it became (-1,49012e-08,0.605945).
It looks like there is some problem when NDVI value become 0
Any ideas about which part I did wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to the formula so we can get more details?

Comment: Brazilian soybean yield prediction using satellite stress indices

Comment: I would recommend editing your post to include a link to the research.